# how to truncate the timestamp to hour and store the column value as a variable in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to store a column value in a table as a variable.
The table looks like this below.

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|timestamp                   |item_name                       |item_value        |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.32, 0.67, 0.32]|
|2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.54, 0.54, 0.3] |
|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.34, 0.25, 0.67]|
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
```

I want to truncate the timestamp to the hour 2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000 and store it as a variable.

the outcome I want is

```
print(timestamp_hour)
'2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000'
```

Comment: Will something like this work out ? 
`SELECT date_trunc('HOUR', '2015-03-05T09:32:05.359');`
`2015-03-05 09:00:00` Refer to thie link https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/date_trunc.html

Answer (score 0):

```
table = """
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|timestamp                   |item_name                       |item_value        |
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
|2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.32, 0.67, 0.32]|
|2023-03-01T17:30:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.54, 0.54, 0.3] |
|2023-03-01T17:20:00.000+0000|[asset_min, hpc_max, off_median]|[0.34, 0.25, 0.67]|
+----------------------------+--------------------------------+------------------+
"""
def timestamp_hour(t_stamp: str) -> str:
    return f'{t_stamp[:13]}:00:00.000+0000'

ltable = table.splitlines()
for line in ltable:
    if '2023-' in line:
        print(timestamp_hour(line[1:28]))
```

Output

```
2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000
2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000
2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: can we do it using a command sth like this date_trunc('hour', df.timestamp))?

Comment: and it's pyspark

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using the [date_trunc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_trunc.html) function and then [collecting](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect.html) the result.
I've applied a [distinct](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct.html) to reduce the data to 1 row before collecting (or multiple if you have multiple hours in the timestamp column).

After collecting we select the first column from the first row.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
timestamp_hour = df.select(F.date_trunc('hour', 'timestamp')).distinct().collect()[0][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this:

```
ts = '2023-03-01T17:35:00.000+0000'
def timestamp_hour(t_stamp: str) -> str:
    return f'{t_stamp[:13]}:00:00.000+0000'

print(timestamp_hour(ts))
```

Output:

```
2023-03-01T17:00:00.000+0000
```

Comment: we have to get a value from the column in a table..